# TypeError when using ItemRendering and a spark GridColumn

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flexbuilder, itemrenderer, flex4.5

I am rendering the `GridColumn`s of spark `DataGrid` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               initialize="doSend()">
    <fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <s:HTTPService id="xmlFromDatabase" method="GET"
                       result="resultHandler(event)" showBusyCursor="true"
                       url="http://localhost:81/PHP-Pro/mys.php"/>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.core.ClassFactory;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        import spark.skins.spark.DefaultItemRenderer;
        import spark.utils.DataItem;
        [Bindable]
        private var datalist:ArrayCollection;
        private var mTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,10);

        private function Countsec(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            lbltime.text=e.target.currentCount;
        }
        private function Comple(e:TimerEvent):void
        {
            lbltime.text="Time Complete";
        }
        private function resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void{
            mTimer.start();
            mTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,Countsec);
            mTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE,Comple);
            datalist = event.result.data.row;
        }
        public function doSend():void {
            xmlFromDatabase.url = "http://localhost:81/PHP-Pro/mys.php";
            xmlFromDatabase.send(); 
        }

        private function FItem_renderer(item:Object, column:GridColumn):ClassFactory{
            //the main logic is here when the value of GridColumn is="SBI" i 
            //should call my user defined renderer else default render
            if (item.FNo=="SBI"){//not working here
                return new ClassFactory(FlightRenderer);    
            } else {
                return new ClassFactory(DefaultItemRenderer);
            }   
        }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Panel left="20" top="20" horizontalCenter="true"
             title="Просмотр рейсов" verticalCenter="true">
        <s:layout>
            <s:FormLayout/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:mxmlContentFactory>
            <s:DataGrid id="dg" x="10" y="10" width="708" height="272" color="#01064D"
                        dataProvider="{datalist}" fontFamily="tahoma">
                <s:columns>
                    <s:ArrayList>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="data" headerText="Дата" itemRendererFunction="FItem_renderer"/>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="FNo" headerText="№рейса" itemRendererFunction="FItem_renderer"/>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="name_ru" headerText="Город" itemRendererFunction="FItem_renderer"/>
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="AirCraft" headerText="ВС" itemRendererFunction="FItem_renderer" />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="FTime" headerText="Время" itemRendererFunction="FItem_renderer"  />
                        <s:GridColumn dataField="Stat" headerText="Статус" itemRendererFunction="FItem_renderer"/>
                    </s:ArrayList>
                </s:columns>
            </s:DataGrid>
        </s:mxmlContentFactory>
    </s:Panel>
    <s:Label id="lbltime" x="41" y="347" fontSize="30" fontWeight="bold" text="Label"/>
</s:Application>
```

And renderer class [FlightRenderer.mxml]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                    clipAndEnableScrolling="true">
    <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
            lblData.text = data[column.dataField]
        }
    ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Rect top="0" bottom="0" right="0" left="0">
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="#E0E0E0" alpha="0.5"/>
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>
    <s:Label id="lblData" top="9" left="7" color="0x505050" alpha="0.5"/>
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```

When I run this app the following error occurs:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at spark.components::Group/addElement()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1342]
    at spark.components.gridClasses::GridLayout/createTypicalItemRenderer()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\gridClasses\GridLayout.as:748]
    at spark.components.gridClasses::GridLayout/updateTypicalCellSizes()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\gridClasses\GridLayout.as:883]
    at spark.components.gridClasses::GridLayout/measure()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\gridClasses\GridLayout.as:444]
    at spark.components.supportClasses::GroupBase/measure()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\supportClasses\GroupBase.as:1148]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/measureSizes()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8496]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8420]
    at spark.components::Group/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\Group.as:1012]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateSize()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:665]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:792]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]
```

I know that I am misusing overriding `defaultItemRender` and don't know what to declare as it's input arguments:

```
private function FItem_renderer(item:Object, column:GridColumn):ClassFactory
```

and how can I check `GridColumn` values in this function?

Comment: Am not sure if you really need to use <s:mxmlContentFactory> in your mxml declaration. It can work without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing what your server is returning, try this. Null safe the if statement, for before the data provider is initialized. Also, you might want to change DefaultItemRenderer to DefaultGridItemRenderer,

```
private function FItem_renderer(item:Object, column:GridColumn):ClassFactory{
                //the main logic is here when the value of GridColumn is="SBI" i 
                //should call my user defined renderer else default render
                if (item && item.FNo=="SBI"){//not working here
                    return new ClassFactory(FlightRenderer);    
                }else
                {
                    return new ClassFactory(DefaultGridItemRenderer);
                }   
            }
```

Comment: You are absolutely right here! You have found where i was wrong too Yesterday i sat till 12pm midnight to fix this problem, and finally found that instead of DefaultGridItemRenderer i returned DefaultItemRenderer which omitted [Grid] between. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Then, how can I call my function renderer every 1 minute on time event handler???

Comment: that's dispatching if I'm not mistaken !

Comment: every time using this code I get error and when i click dismiss all it gets run then. I know that when I created an instance of `ArrayCollection` like `private var datalist:ArrayCollection` and the assigned xml data using  `datalist = event.result.data.row;` I am setting wrong 1 st input parameter in `FItem_renderer(item:Object, column:GridColumn)` function because it's not Object if it were i would have created it like `<fx:Object var="val">` then if could set the first parameter of my function renderer as Object type and could check getting it's property's value using `item.var`.

Comment: As my datalist that I set to dataprovider is an instance of `ArrayCollection` what type of first parameter of my function renderer should i use in that case???? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you can still use array collection, the signature in the method above cannot change. Instead, what you do with it will change, I'd recommend casting it to a local variable of type ArrayCollection and then operating on it.
    `var ac:ArrayCollection = ArrayCollection(item);`
    `ac.getItemAt(0).doSomething();`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to be like you are setting your data improperly.  You should set your data by overriding the `data` setter or in this case just bind `data` directly to your `Label`'s `text` property like this:

```
<s:Label 
    id="lblData" 
    text="{data}"
    top="9" 
    left="7" 
    color="0x505050" 
    alpha="0.5"/>
```

Also eliminate your override of `prepare`.

Comment: It doesn't matter I am assigning value using `lblData.text = data[column.dataField]` and column is an default input argument of my renderer overrided function! It's working coooooooool for now ! You can also do this by binding features!